# How to find the current logged in user ID programmatically?

Tags: unix

I tried uid and euid, but it gives me the owner of current running program.

I need to get the user ID of the current user who has logged into the system.

Also, is it possible to distinguish the current user from other simultaneously logged in users, in a multi user system?

Comment: You should add more details about the program you are running, how it is invoked, if it is a setuid/setgid program. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. whoami is one option, it simply echoes out the user id.

```
whoami
current_user_id
```

From the man page: `man whoami`- print effective userid.

There is already a defined environment variable with this information set by login as well. To utilize this, try the following:

```
echo $USER
current_user_id
```

You can verify this with the `man login`.

If you need more data about the current user such as uid, gid and groups, you can use:

```
id
uid=realuid(effective_id) gid=real_gid(effective_gid) groups=real_group1_id(effective_group1_id),real_group2_id(effective_group2_id)
```

This can be verified with `man id`.

It really comes down to what information you need, and how you're going to use it.